# Random change the order of rows in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which have one column like this:

```
> df$stocks
1 stock1
2 stock2
3 stock3
4 stock4
```

Is there any function which changes randomly the order of rows when I execute it like the first time I execute it the result of the data frame will be:

```
 > df$stocks
    1 stock2
    2 stock1
    3 stock4
    4 stock3
```

The next time will be something different etc.

Comment: Use `sample` and basic `[row, col]` to get started.

Comment: Or just use Google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sample`

```
df$name[sample(nrow(df))]
```

Comment: or we can mark it as dupe and just leave the comment. The comment was fine...